# What is the best way to merge two dataframes that one of them has date ranges and the other one has date WITHOUT any shared columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date': ['2024-01-01','2024-01-02', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-04', '2024-01-05', '2024-01-06', '2024-01-07', '2024-01-08', '2024-01-09', '2024-01-10', '2024-01-11', '2024-01-12', '2024-01-13'],
        'price': list(range(13))
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'start': ['2024-01-01', '2024-01-03', '2024-01-10'],
        'end': ['2024-01-03', '2024-01-08', '2024-01-12'],
        'id': ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
)
```

And this is the expected output. I want to add `id` to `df1`:

```
         date  price   id
0  2024-01-01      0  NaN
1  2024-01-02      1    a
2  2024-01-03      2    a
3  2024-01-04      3    b
4  2024-01-05      4    b
5  2024-01-06      5    b
6  2024-01-07      6    b
7  2024-01-08      7    b
8  2024-01-09      8  NaN
9  2024-01-10      9  NaN
10 2024-01-11     10    c
11 2024-01-12     11    c
12 2024-01-13     12  NaN
```

The process is like this. Let me give you an example for row `1` of the output:

**a)** The `date` is 2024-01-02. Look up `df2`. There is a range for each row of `df2`. This `date` is between the first row of `df2`. Note that `start` is exclusive and `end` is inclusive.

**b)** Get the `id` from the identified row in `df2` and put in the output.

Since there are no common columns between these two DataFrames, I have used a loop to get the output. It works but I am not sure if it is the best way:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)
df2[['start', 'end']] = df2[['start', 'end']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
for idx, row in df2.iterrows():
    start = row['start']
    end = row['end']
    id = row['id']

    df1.loc[df1.date.between(start, end, inclusive='right'), 'id'] = id
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a very common duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another options, use `pd.cut`:

```py
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2["start"], df2["end"])
df1["id"] = pd.cut(df1["date"], bins).map(dict(zip(bins, df2["id"])))

print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
         date  price   id
0  2024-01-01      0  NaN
1  2024-01-02      1    a
2  2024-01-03      2    a
3  2024-01-04      3    b
4  2024-01-05      4    b
5  2024-01-06      5    b
6  2024-01-07      6    b
7  2024-01-08      7    b
8  2024-01-09      8  NaN
9  2024-01-10      9  NaN
10 2024-01-11     10    c
11 2024-01-12     11    c
12 2024-01-13     12  NaN
```